# Double strip of spaces in string (ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have this string:

```
"item one :value1 , item2: value2,item3 : value3"
```

how can i  obtain this one?:

```
"item one:value1,item2:value2,item3:value3"
```

(i need to strip spaces between ","-separated items , and between ":"-separated items)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
irb(main):008:0> "item one :value1 , item2: value2,item3 : value3".gsub(/\s*([,:])\s*/,'\1')
=> "item one:value1,item2:value2,item3:value3"
```